# EDI 856 Where to put Carrier and Tracking Info

Tags: edi, x12

We are trying to design our standard 856 for customers that are not on EDI yet.

I've been researching where to put the carrier information.

Seems like some people recommend putting the tracking # here:

> REF*CN*1Z6Y654R1359137591~

I've seen "CN" for Carrier Number, and I've seen other use "ZH".

Where would I put the fact that it's FedEx, USP, USPS, etc... 
Would that just be another reference with a different code? 
I'm trying to find how most people already do it. 
I've found several 856 implementation guides, but it's not clear where they put the carrier name especially.

Comment: Usually it is placed in TD5 segment

Comment: TD5 segment, 3rd or 5th element

Comment: Thanks, if you put in answer I can vote it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Artem has mentioned, the 5th element of the TD5 segment is the usual place for a carrier name.

As for a tracking number, I've not seen this in the TD5 segment before. You could use the REF segment with a qualifier of 2I which is the qualifier which specifically means "Tracking Number".

Comment: Is the Qualifier totally user defined between you and your trading partner?  When I searched for "REF01" in EDI856 and find many implementation guidelines, seems like many of them use "CN".  I'm using BizTalk which has a complete list of codes, but doesn't have the corresponding meanings, is there any one place to find the meaning for all the REF01 codes?

Comment: I actually don't know where these can be found online. I have the X12 documentation stored locally (I work for in the industry) but it was originally taken from "ftp://ftp.premenos.com/pub/outgoing/edifact/directories/d96b/UN-disk/ " in the year 2000... I've searched unsuccessfully for the source, but it is not user defined stuff.

CN is just as valid and is defined as "Carrier's Reference Number (PRO/Invoice)".